I can't select a table from my databricks DBs in SQL - error AnalysisException: Delta table `default`.`incidents` doesn't exist
I am just starting out in databricks using SQL, and I just want to select a table and see the fields/columns , I know the table exists when you check the DB catalog but when I try to select it using * from table_name, I get this error AnalysisException: Delta table default.incidents doesn't exist.
I know for a fact it exists so Im not sure why its doing that. Any advice? Do I need to add another filepath parameter or DB name?
I tried creating my own new table and that worked. But copying/cloning a table does not work, it keeps saying it doesnt exists.
I checked the DB catalog and confirmed the table exists, and I tried other tables as well.

You will have to either add the schema name to your query or use the current_database() function to figure out if you are querying the correct database.
https://docs.databricks.com/en/sql/language-manual/functions/current_database.html
